# Pegar valores checkbox com javascript e exibir dados do banco

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estou fazendo um carrinho de compras em PHP. Tenho dois checkbox (Buscar no balcão e Entrega) e preciso que no momento que o usuario clicar no checkbox *Entrega* o valor da taxa de entrega vindo do Banco seja calculado com o total do pedido.

*Meu código:*

```
      <form action"conteudo.php" name="frm" method="GET">
            <span class="servicos"><input id="bus"type="radio" name="rad" value="1">             Buscar no balcão<br>
        </span>
            <span class="servicos"><input id="bus"type="radio"name="rad" value"2"> Entrega</span>
                    </form>

    `<table width="310" border="1">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Excluir</td>
                          <td>Qtde</td>
                          <td>Produto</td>
                          <td>Valor</td>       
                        </tr>
                        <br>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                           <?php
                          foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtde) {
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE ID_PRODUTO = '$id'";
                            $end = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                            while($resu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($end)){

                            $nome  = $resu['NOME_PRO'];
                            $preco = FormataValor($resu['PRECO_P']);
                            $sub   = $resu['PRECO_P'] * $qtde;
                            $total += $sub ;

                            <tr>
                              <td><a href="?acao=del&id='.$id.'">&#10148;</a></td>
                              <td>'.$qtde.'</td>
                              <td>'.$nome.'</td>
                              <td>R$'.$preco.'</td>
                            <tr>  
                              <td colspan="4"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>  
                              <td colspan="4"></td>
                            </tr>';
                               }
                           }

                          ?> 

                     </tbody>

                     <tfoot>
                        </form>
                        <tr>  
                            <td colspan="4"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>  
                            <td colspan="4"></td>
                            </tr>  
                        <tr>  
                          <td colspan="3">SubTotal</td>
                          <td>R$<?php echo FormataValor($total);?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>  
                          <td colspan="3">Taxa Entrega</td>
                          <td><?php 
                          if(isset($_GET['rad'])){
                            echo $resu['TAXA_ENTREGA'];}?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>  
                          <td colspan="3">Total</td>
                          <td>R$<?php echo FormataValor($total) ;?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                  </table>
                  <a href="index.php">Continuar Comprando</a`>
```

Comment: Esse código que você postou o que tem nele?

Comment: Ola Marconi, esse codigo é um carrrinho de compra,feito em php, quando eu adiciono um produto eu consigo excluir o produto, calcular o total e subtotal , o que eu desejo fazer é a partir do checkbox é trazer um valor de taxa de entrega do banco para o usuario , quando clicar no check entrega já adicione a taxa de entrega exemplo 2,00 esse valor vindo do banco e no mesmo instante calcular no total

Comment: Quando você diz banco você quer dizer banco de dados ou literalmente banco?

Comment: Banco de Dados estou usando o MYSQL

Comment: Vou dar uma sugestão, você poderia criar uma atributo data(exemplo data-taxa) no checkbox e manipular esse valor pelo JavaScript quando ele clicar no checkbox, apenas para mostrar pro usuário. Já no php, repete o processo para não dar margem de alteração.

Comment: Desculpa Lucao, sou bem leigo ainda não consegui entender ao certo sua sugestão